# Clarity on the word blur, blurred and blurry

Tags: sentence-construction, participial-adjectives

Which one is correct:

> The phone camera **is blur**.

or

> The phone camera **is blurred**.

Comment: Hi @Fatima, this site does not do proofreading, and your question will likely be closed. Why not take the [site tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour)? Also, the correct answer is the latter -- you might want to check [this site](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/adjectiv/particip.htm) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

"Blurred" is the past tense of the verb *to blur*. It is also an adjective to describe something that *is* blurred, as in the case of your example. "Blurry" essentially means the same as "blurred", although it can be used to describe varying degrees of blurriness. An image is either blurred, or it is not - but you could say it is "*very blurry*", or "*a little blurry*".

So, the correct word for your sentence would be:

> The phone camera is *blurred*.

However, is it actually the *camera* that is blurred, or the *photographs* it takes? Although "lens blur" is a recognised term for the effect of blurring photographs, "blurred" isn't a quality that a camera has.

I would be more inclined to say:

> The phone camera takes blurred (or blurry) photographs.